# ansible how do i search for a directory/subdirectory like 'home/ansible'

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, find

In Ansible v2.8.2, how do I search for a subset of a directory tree, like 'home/ansible'?

I have attempted using the find module:

```
    - name: Find ansible directory
      become: true
      find:
          paths: /
          recurse: yes
          file_type: directory
          use_regex: yes
          patterns: 'home/ansible'
      register: ansible_dirs

    - name: post ansible dirs
      debug:
          msg:
              - "{{ ansible_dirs }}"
```

I get the error: `/proc/20828/task/20828/fd/6 was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid file or it cannot be accessed`

If I change patterns to 'home' or 'ansible' it works, but gives me more results then I need.

I suppose I could take this larger result set and whittle it down to what I need, but I was hoping there was an out-of-the-box method to use.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From the doc: `The pattern is matched against the file base name, excluding the directory.` So what you are trying to do can't work (with the find module at least). You might consider in this specific case using `locate` if available through the `shell`module. I don't know any ansible module able to meet your requirement (but I'd happily be proven wrong).

Comment: @Zeitounator that is what I am thinking as well, but I hope I am wrong too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think the find module does a primitive search. Thus it can not access everything through permission restrictions or would take forever in very big mounted network storages.

Therefore it might be helpful to restrict your search.

If you just want to test if the specific path exist (have not tested if directories work like files):

```
- name: Wait until the file /tmp/foo is present before continuing
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/foo
```

Or you might exclude paths where you don't expect your findings:

excludes might the option you are looking within the find module.

```
- name: Find /var/log all directories, exclude nginx and mysql
  find:
    paths: /var/log
    recurse: no
    file_type: directory
    excludes: 'nginx,mysql'
```

Code extractions are taken from Ansible documentation examples.

Comment: I am using `home/ansible` as an example, but what i am ultimately trying to do is find the install directory for a product, say 'product1' ... when I search using the find module with the pattern of 'product1', it comes back with a multitude of results, because there are various directories that include that pattern. So to get the install directory, I would actually want to search for the subset of 'webapps/product1' as the pattern. The example you use above doesn't allow for this, because the "paths" expects a specific directory. I have a feeling no module does this, but I was hoping lol

Comment: Ok. If the product gets installed by a package manager you could parse the installation script. Or if the product binary is within the $PATH, then you could do "which <binary-name>". But without additional information I also just see a script trying to walk through all paths and trying to perform pattern matching on it.

Comment: The product was installed in various different ways on the hundreds of servers. So the easiest solution is to search for the pattern `webapps/product1`, because that will show the true location. I had hopes that the `find` module, using `file_type` of directory, would be able to handle this, but apparently it can only search for a simple pattern. Thanks!